How do I use the entire /48 IPv6 Subnet with my Ubuntu Server - adding the subnet doesn't work to eth0 or lo
Please do help me out. As I am stuck with this for past 6 days and I broke few keys off my keyboard already being in stress.
I also have this idea of installing netplan if it fixes, I just don't want to break the server in the process as I don't know to configure it
I have used linode and few other providers before and when I deploy a /48 /56 or /64 subnet on a Ubuntu Machine, I just use these following commands to add them to my VPS and they start to work. But this new machine I got isn't letting me setup my subnet assigned to me using the same command. It worked with 6+ providers and I re-tested it on 4 providers today just to make sure I am not buzzing out or any new update on Ubuntu has not been made. I use UBUNTU 22/20
ifconfig -a (to know the router name) (sometimes its eth0 sometimes ens18)
then
ip route add local 2a0c:8fc3:0059::/48 dev eth0 (or ens18)
ip -6 addr add 2a0c:8fc3:0059::1/48 dev lo
And subnet starts to work. And starts assigning IP to my load balancer application or any other application or if I wish to ping each IPv6 from my PC over TCP, I can easily ping any of the IP of the whole of subnet.
The only difference is that,
The new provider has /etc/network/interfaces and Linode and others had /etc/netplan
With netplan the config looks simple, no subnet details, gateway etc needs to be feeded and subnet easily works with just me adding with the above command.
I have tried the same command I have been using for past 2 years to add a subnet to a server i.e.
ip route add local 2a0c:8fc3:0059::/48 dev eth0 (or ens18)
ip -6 addr add 2a0c:8fc3:0059::1/48 dev lo
but here it doesn't seem to work.
Here is the  /etc/network/interfaces config of the new server where I am unable to make the subnet work, I don't want to just install netplan as I don't know to set it up, as it came pre-configured on all the VPS or Dedi I purchased since last 2 years, this is the only one I have network/interfaces with and I am confused what is not making the subnet to not work.
 # The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 84.33.244.xx (My server primary IP)
netmask 255.255.255.0

broadcast 84.33.244.xx (my IP)
post-up route add 84.33.244.1 dev eth0
post-up route add default gw 84.33.244.1 dev eth0
iface eth0 inet6 static
        accept_ra 0
        address 2a0c:8fc3:0059:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001
        netmask 48


post-up /sbin/ip -r route add 2a0c:8fc3::1 dev eth0
post-up /sbin/ip -r route add default via 2a0c:8fc3::1 


The subnet in Question which I got assigned and wish to setup is 2a0c:8fc3:0059::/48
This is Their Manual on How to Setup the Subnet
You should receive at least one /64 IPv4 subnet with each KVM-based cloud or virtual private server (VPS), most of the time even a larger subnet like /56 or /48 is provisioned.

IPv6 is native on our infrastructure and on all servers that are automatically provisioned have a working IPv6 configuration, but if you want to manually configure IPv6 or need advanced networking information please make reference to the following:

you can find the IPv6 subnet assigend to your server in the control panel, typically something like 2001:1a38:<your specific /48 subnet prefix>::/48 or like 2a0c:8fc0:<your specific /48 subnet prefix>::/48, e. g. 2a0c:8fc0:cafe::/48 (this is your IPv6 subnet)
your default gateway then is 2a0c:8fc0:cafe::fffe (your complete IPv6 subnet without the netmask (e. g. /48) with ::fffe added at the end)
In other words:

Gateway:

if your IPv6 is xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::1/48, then your Gateway will be – xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::fffe
if your IPv6 is xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxAA::1/56 then your Gateway will be – xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::fffe
if your IPv6 is xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::1/64 then your Gateway will be – xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::fffe
We normally do not give out IPv6 subnets "smaller" than /64 (as this breaks some important IPv6 functionality) or larger than /48 (only for very specific needs a larger prefix than the "site"-prefix is necessary).

If you plan to manually configure your network - IPv4 or IPv6 - of your KVM-based cloud or virtual private server and your control panel is Virtualizor, please do not forget to open a ticket and ask for us to disable the automatic network configuration of Virtualizor, as otherwise your network configuration will be overwritten each time you stop, start or reboot your server from the control panel. Currently this needs to be done manually.

